# Loop through a set of functions with Haskell

Tags: haskell, loops, recursion, while-loop, list-comprehension

Here's a simple, barebones example of how the code that I'm trying to do would look in C++.

```
while (state == true) {
  a = function1();
  b = function2();
  state = function3();
}
```

In the program I'm working on, I have some functions that I need to loop through until bool *state* equals false (or until one of the variables, let's say variable b, equals 0).

How would this code be done in Haskell? I've searched through here, Google, and even Bing and haven't been able to find any clear, straight forward explanations on how to do repetitive actions with functions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The code you posted is inherently imperative. While it is possible to write code in an imperative style in Haskell, it's not usually the best approach. I think you should start from a higher level concept of what the code is doing and try to translate that into a functional solution.

Comment: You're right... I'm still struggling with trying to translate my C++ way of thinking into a functional language. But I can't think of any other way to do this without some kind of a loop. In my program, some functions have to be called multiple times until all conditions are met.

Comment: You should tell us what you're _actually_ trying to do here so we can help you rework it into a functional solution.

Comment: I'm trying to make a data analysis app that operates through natural language processing. >_< I probably should have started with Hello World... I've made a lot of progress. The prompt can reply to questions. But it can only reply once, hence the need for a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking Daniels comment into account, it could look something like this:

```
f = loop init_a init_b true
    where
         loop a b True = loop a' b' (fun3 a' b')
             where
                 a' = fun1 ....
                 b' = fun2 .....
         loop a b False = (a,b)
```

Comment: So Haskell does have a loop?? If the feature is there, I might as well use it. :D But I'll try to plan ahead better for my next project, and build the program in a way to use recursion instead of loops. I do want to learn how to use Haskell the *right* way.

Thank you.

Comment: @SubtleArray I think you are misinterpreting something, the code above defines a function called loop. It is not using any primitive loop constructs (except perhaps, recursion).

Comment: I just learned that the hard way. I was like "Why isn't this loop working??" :D It works well though. Right now I'm trying to mold this into something more Haskelly and recursive using a pattern matching function that calls other functions. I might be able to get it to work.

Comment: That said, there *are* in fact "loopy" constructs in Haskell, most notably `until` and `iterate`.

Comment: +1 and kudos for the straight answer. Both `fun1` and `fun2` could refer to state though too, so probably a third variable should've just been created there: `loop a b c@True = loop a' b' c' where ... ; c' = fun3 ...` Also, strictness annotations (bang patterns) might be an inseparable part of a loop specification, since constant space operation is usually desired.

Answer (score 5):

Well, here's a suggestion of how to map the concepts here:

- A C++ loop is some form of list operation in Haskell.
- One iteration of the loop = handling one element of the list.
- Looping until a certain condition becomes true = base case of a function that recurses on a list.

But there is something that is critically different between imperative loops and functional list functions: **loops describe *how* to iterate; higher-order list functions describe the structure of the computation**.  So for example, `map f [a0, a1, ..., an]` can be described by this diagram:

```
[a0,   a1,   ..., an]
 |     |          |
 f     f          f
 |     |          |
 v     v          v
[f a0, f a1, ..., f an]
```

Note that this describes how the result is related to the arguments `f` and `[a0, a1, ..., an]`, not how the iteration is performed step by step.

Likewise, `foldr f z [a0, a1, ..., an]` corresponds to this:

```
f a0 (f a1 (... (f an z)))
```

`filter` doesn't quite lend itself to diagramming, but it's easy to state many rules that it satisfies:

- `length (filter pred xs) <= length xs`
- For every element `x` of `filter pred xs`, `pred x` is `True`.
- If `x` is an element of `filter pred xs`, then `x` is an element of `xs`
- If `x` is not an element of `xs`, then `x` is not an element of `filter pred xs`
- If `x` appears before `x'` in `filter pred xs`, then `x` appears before `x'` in `xs`
- If `x` appears before `x'` in `xs`, and both `x` and `x'` appear in `filter pred xs`, then `x` appears before `x'` in `filter pred xs`

In a classic imperative program, all three of these cases are written as loops, and the difference between them comes down to what the loop body does.  Functional programming, on the contrary, insists that this sort of structural pattern does not belong in "loop bodies" (the functions `f` and `pred` in these examples); rather, these patterns are best abstracted out into higher-order functions like `map`, `foldr` and `filter`.  Thus, every time you see one of these list functions you instantly know some important facts about how the arguments and the result are related, without having to read any code; whereas in a typical imperative program, you must read the bodies of loops to figure this stuff out.

So the real answer to your question is that it's impossible to offer an idiomatic translation of an imperative loop into functional terms without knowing what the loop body is doing—what are the preconditions supposed to be before the loop runs, and what the postconditions are supposed to be when the loop finishes.  Because that loop body that you only described vaguely is going to determine what the structure of the computation is, and different such structures will call for different higher-order functions in Haskell.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let's think about a few things.

- Does `function1` have side effects?
- Does `function2` have side effects?
- Does `function3` have side effects?

The answer to all of these is a resoundingly obvious YES, because they take no inputs, and presumably there are circumstances which cause you to go around the while loop more than once (rather than `def function3(): return false`). Now let's remodel these functions with explicit state.

```
s = initialState
sentinel = true
while(sentinel):
  a,b,s,sentinel = function1(a,b,s,sentinel)
  a,b,s,sentinel = function2(a,b,s,sentinel)
  a,b,s,sentinel = function3(a,b,s,sentinel)
return a,b,s
```

Well that's rather ugly. We know absolutely nothing about what inputs each function draws from, nor do we know anything about how these functions might affect the variables `a`, `b`, and `sentinel`, nor "any other state" which I have simply modeled as `s`.

So let's make a few assumptions. Firstly, I am going to assume that these functions do not directly depend on nor affect in any way the values of `a`, `b`, and `sentinel`. They might, however, change the "other state". So here's what we get:

```
s = initState
sentinel = true
while (sentinel):
  a,s2 = function1(s)
  b,s3 = function2(s2)
  sentinel,s4 = function(s3)
  s = s4
return a,b,s
```

Notice I've used temporary variables `s2`, `s3`, and `s4` to indicate the changes that the "other state" goes through. Haskell time. We need a control function to behave like a `while` loop.

```
myWhile :: s                   -- an initial state
        -> (s -> (Bool, a, s)) -- given a state, produces a sentinel, a current result, and the next state
        -> (a, s)              -- the result, plus resultant state
myWhile s f = case f s of
  (False, a, s') -> (a, s')
  (True,  _, s') -> myWhile s' f
```

Now how would one use such a function? Well, given we have the functions:

```
function1 :: MyState -> (AType, MyState)
function2 :: MyState -> (BType, MyState)
function3 :: MyState -> (Bool,  MyState)
```

We would construct the desired code as follows:

```
thatCodeBlockWeAreTryingToSimulate :: MyState -> ((AType, BType), MyState)
thatCodeBlockWeAreTryingToSimulate initState = myWhile initState f
  where f :: MyState -> (Bool, (AType, BType), MyState)
        f s = let (a, s2) = function1 s
                  (b, s3) = function2 s2
                  (sentinel, s4) = function3 s3
              in (sentinel, (a, b), s4)
```

Notice how similar this is to the non-ugly python-like code given above.

You can verify that the code I have presented is well-typed by adding `function1 = undefined` etc for the three functions, as well as the following at the top of the file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}    
data MyState
data AType
data BType
```

---

So the takeaway message is this: in Haskell, you must explicitly model the changes in state. You can use the "State Monad" to make things a little prettier, but you should first understand the idea of passing state around.

Comment: Exercise for the reader: instead of using `myWhile`, try to write `thatCodeBlockWeAreTryingToSimulate` using `unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]`. Hints: the type `b` corresponds to the type `s`, and the `Maybe` takes the place of the `Bool`. What additional information do you gain by using `unfoldr`? What information do you lose?

Answer (score 2):

Lets take a look at your C++ loop:

```
while (state == true) {
  a = function1();
  b = function2();
  state = function3();
}
```

Haskell is a pure functional language, so it won't fight us as much (and the resulting code will be more useful, both in itself and as an exercise to learn Haskell) if we try to do this without side effects, and without using monads to make it look like we're using side effects either.

Lets start with this structure

```
while (state == true) {
   <<do stuff that updates state>>
}
```

In Haskell we're obviously not going to be checking a variable against `true` as the loop condition, because it can't change its value[1] and we'd either evaluate the loop body forever or never. So instead, we'll want to be evaluating a function that returns a boolean value on some argument:

```
while (check something == True) {
  <<do stuff that updates state>>
}
```

Well, now we don't have a `state` variable, so that "do stuff that updates state" is looking pretty pointless. And we don't have a `something` to pass to `check`. Lets think about this a bit more. We want the `something` to be checked to depend on what the "do stuff" bit is doing. We don't have side effects, so that means `something` has to be (or be derived from) returned from the "do stuff". "do stuff" also needs to take something that varies as an argument, or it'll just keep returning the same thing forever, which is also pointless. We also need to return a value out all this, otherwise we're just burning CPU cycles (again, with no side effects there's no point running a function if we don't use its output in some way, and there's even less point running a function repeatedly if we never use its output).

So how about something like this:

```
while check func state =
    let next_state = func state in
    if check next_state
      then while check func next_state
      else next_state
```

Lets try it in GHCi:

```
*Main> while (<20) (+1) 0
20
```

This is the result of applying (+1) repeatedly while the result is less than 20, starting from 0.

```
*Main> while ((<20) . length) (++ "zob") ""
"zobzobzobzobzobzobzob"
```

This is the result of concatenating "zob" repeatedly while the result's length is less than 20, starting from the empty string.

So you can see I've defined a function that is (sort of a bit) analogous to a `while` loop from imperative languages. We didn't even need dedicated loop syntax for it! (which is the real reason Haskell has no such syntax; if you need this kind of thing you can express it as a function). It's not the only way to do so, and experienced Haskell programmers would probably use other standard library functions to do this kind of job, rather than writing `while`.

But I think it's useful to see how you can express this kind of thing in Haskell. It does show that you can't translate things like imperative loops *directly* into Haskell; I didn't end up translating your loop in terms of my `while` because it ends up pretty pointless; you never use the result of `function1` or `function2`, they're called with no arguments so they'd always return the same thing in every iteration, and `function3` likewise always returns the same thing, and can only return `true` or `false` to either cause `while` to keep looping or stop, with no information resulting.

Presumably in the C++ program they're all using side effects to actually get some work done. If they operate on in-memory things then you need to translate a bigger chunk of your program at once to Haskell for the translation of this loop to make any sense. If those functions are doing IO then you'll need to do this in the `IO` monad in Haskell, for which my `while` function doesn't work, but you can do something similar.

---

[1] As an aside, it's worth trying to understand that "you can't change variables" in Haskell isn't just an arbitrary restriction, nor is it just an acceptable trade off for the benefits of purity, it is a concept that **doesn't make sense the way Haskell wants you to think about Haskell code**. You're writing down expressions that result from evaluating functions on certain arguments: in `f x = x + 1` you're saying that `f x` **is** `x + 1`. If you really think of it that way rather than thinking "f takes x, then adds one to it, then returns the result" then the concept of "having side effects" doesn't even apply; how could something existing and being equal to something else somehow change a variable, or have some other side effect?

Answer (score 1):

You should write a solution to your problem in a more functional approach.
However, some code in haskell works a lot like imperative looping, take for example state monads, terminal recursivity, `until`, `foldr`, etc.

A simple example is the factorial. In C, you would write a loop where in haskell you can for example write `fact n = foldr (*) 1 [2..n]`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there a way to apply *until* or *foldr* to functions rather than integers?

Comment: Here `foldr` is applied to the function multiply `(*)`. The first state is represented by `1` and then the "current loop result" is modified by combining the previous state and the argument from the list.

Comment: `unfoldr` is another useful "looping" operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you've two functions `f :: a -> b` and `g :: b -> c` where `a`, `b`, and `c` are types like `String` or `[Int]` then you can compose them simply by writing `f . b`.

If you wish them to loop over a list or vector you could write `map (f . g)` or `V.map (f . g)`, assuming you've done `Import qualified Data.Vector as V`.

Example :  I wish to print a list of markdown headings like `## <number>. <heading> ##` but I need roman numerals numbered from 1 and my list `headings` has type type `[(String,Double)]` where the `Double` is irrelevant.

```
Import Data.List
Import Text.Numeral.Roman
let fun = zipWith (\a b -> a ++ ". " ++ b ++ "##\n") (map toRoman [1..]) . map fst
fun [("Foo",3.5),("Bar",7.1)]
```

What the hell does this do?

`toRoman` turns a number into a string containing the roman numeral.  `map toRoman` does this to every element of a loop.  `map toRoman [1..]` does it to every element of the lazy infinite list `[1,2,3,4,..]`, yielding a lazy infinite list of roman numeral strings

`fst :: (a,b) -> a` simply extracts the first element of a tuple.  `map fst` throws away our silly `Meow` information along the entire list.

`\a b -> "##" ++ show a ++ ". " ++ b ++ "##"` is a lambda expression that takes two strings and concatenates them together within the desired formatting strings.

`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]` takes a two argument function like our lambda expression and feeds it pairs of elements from it's own second and third arguments.

You'll observe that `zip`, `zipWith`, etc. only read as much of the lazy infinite list of Roman numerals as needed for the list of headings, meaning I've number my headings without maintaining any counter variable.

Finally, I have declared `fun` without naming it's argument because the compiler can figure it out from the fact that `map fst` requires one argument.  You'll notice that put a `.` before my second map too.  I could've written `(map fst h)` or `$ map fst h` instead if I'd written `fun h = ...`, but leaving the argument off `fun` meant I needed to compose it with `zipWith` after applying `zipWith` to two arguments of the three arguments zipWith wants.

I'd hope the compiler combines the `zipWith` and `map`s into one single loop via inlining.